# Continued fraction: Show $\sqrt{n^2+2n}=[n; \overline{1,2n}]$

Tags: continued-fractions

I have to show the following identity ($n \in \mathbb{N}$):

$$\sqrt{n^2+2n}=[n; \overline{1,2n}]$$

I had a look about the procedure for $\sqrt{n}$ on [Wiki](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Continued_Fraction_Expansion_of_Irrational_Square_Root), but I don't know how to transform it to $\sqrt{n^2-2n}$.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

I tried the following:

$\sqrt{n^2+2n}>n$, so we get $\sqrt{n^2+2n}=n+\frac{n}{x}$, and $\sqrt{n^2+2n}-n=\frac{n}{x}$ and further $x=\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+2n}}$.

So we get $x=\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+2n}-n}=\frac{n(\sqrt{n^2+2n}+n)}{(\sqrt{n^2+2n}-n)(\sqrt{n^2+2n}+n}$ I don't know if it's right and how to go on.

Comment: I think the minus sign should be a plus, because $\sqrt{n^2-2n}<n$.

Comment: Oh, You're right. Thanks.

Comment: Just need to compute continued fraction like you would with (say) $n=3$. What's left is $\sqrt{n^2+2n}-n$. Flip it over, rationalize (so $1/x$, not $n/x$). We get $(\sqrt{n^2+2n}+n)/2$. Greatest integer in this is $1$. Subtract $1$, flip over. Continue. The end is near!

Comment: Incidentally, the first core flaw here comes from your writing of $\sqrt{n^2+2n}$ as $n+{n\over x}$ - remember that a proper continued fraction has all of its numerators equal to $1$, so you want to be writing it as $n+{1\over x}$.  From there, it's just a lot of algebra and some judicious inequalities...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $n^2+2n=(n+1)^2-1$, the leading term in the continued fraction expansion will be $n$.  Multiplying by a form of $1$, we have

$$\sqrt{n^2+2n}-n=\frac{2n}{n+\sqrt{n^2+2n}}$$
 and $1<\frac{n+\sqrt{n^2+2n}}{2n}<2,$ so the next term will be $1$.  Since $\frac{n+\sqrt{n^2+2n}}{2n}-1=\frac{\sqrt{n^2+2n}-n}{2n}$ and we can again rationalize the denominator to simplify $\frac{2n}{\sqrt{n^2+2n}-n}=n+\sqrt{n^2+2n}$.  Because $n<\sqrt{n^2+2n}<n+1$, the next term in the continued fraction expansion is $2n$, and subtracting 2n yields $\sqrt{n^2+2n}-n$, at which point the pattern continues.

In the end, it all boils down to the useful trick that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}}=\frac{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}{a-b}$, which can be viewed as a application of $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$.  Judging from your edit, you are aware of this idea, but you just didn't carry out the necessary algebraic simplifications to see that it actually leads somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT** $\rm\  x = [\overline{1,2n}]\ \Rightarrow\  x\ = \cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{2\:n+x}}\ \iff\ x^2 + 2\:n\ x - 2\:n = 0\ \iff\ x = -n \pm \sqrt{n^2 + 2\:n} $

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll write down my idea:$\Rightarrow\ x+n=\pm \sqrt{n^2+2n}$ and so $[n;\overline{1,2n}]=\pm \sqrt{n^2+2n}$ And now I'm done?

Comment: While this _shows_ the identity, I'd say it doesn't _derive_ it - this certainly works but it's also good to see where the identity comes from.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki My answer was posted before the OP edited the question. The initial version of the question asked only for a proof ("show the following identity").

Answer (score 2):

The first few convergents of $[3;\overline{1,6}]$ are $3,4,\frac{27}7,\frac{31}8,\frac{213}{55}$, and $\frac{244}{63}$; $\frac{213}{55}=3.8\overline{72}$, and $\frac{244}{63}$ is a little over $3.873$, so $[3;\overline{1,6}]$ is clearly not $\sqrt{3^2-2\cdot3}=\sqrt3$.

In fact, $n^2-2n=(n-1)^2-1$, so the integer part and first convergent of $\sqrt{n^2-2n}$ will be $n-2$. But $\sqrt{n^2-2n}$ isn’t $[n-2;\overline{1,2n}]$, either, since, as you can see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Infinite_continued_fractions), $\sqrt3=[1;\overline{1,2}]$.

$\sqrt8=[2;\overline{1,4}]$, so your identity should probably be $\sqrt{n^2-2n}=[n-2;\overline{1,2(n-2)}]$ for $n\ge 3$.

Now let $m=n-2$ and consider the continued fraction $x=[m;\overline{1,2m}]$.

$$\begin{align*}
x+m&=[2m;\overline{1,2m}]\\
&=2m+\frac1{1+\frac1{[2m;\overline{1,2m}]}}\\
&=2m+\frac1{1+\frac1{x+m}}\\
&=2m+\frac{x+m}{x+m+1}\\
&=\frac{(2m+1)x+2m^2+3m}{x+m+1}\;,
\end{align*}$$

and you can finish it off by solving for $x$ in terms of $m$ (and then in terms of $n$).

If the identity was supposed to have $\sqrt{n^2+2n}$ on the lefthand side, the same basic approach will work, though the details will obviously be different, and you won’t need $m$.

**Added:** I see that you have edited the problem statement to make the lefthand side $\sqrt{n^2+2n}$; I’ll leave my solution to the original version as an extended hint for the corrected version.

Comment: Very nice answer, I'll try to understand it :) Thanks a lot.